# Hide ajax-injected elements without touching the ajax call itself

Tags: jquery, ajax

In short, I need to pre-emptively hide elements that will load in a future script.

I am working in a large and messy application. On a particular page, I can run any javascript/jQuery I want, and after it finishes another module will run which I cannot control. This second module injects elements into the DOM that must never be shown to the user (clunky, yes? it's just this particular page that should feature this reversed, unusual behavior; the injected elements are appropriate on all other pages). The point is that I have no access to the ajax call that loads the unwanted DOM elements.

I was thinking of injecting a CSS stylesheet into the page, but I'd like to compare alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use css. This will reduce the latency. If you inject styles after everything is loaded, it will have a "flash" style, meaning it could appear for awhile before disappearing. A user with a slow connection would suffer from this, and mobile devices. If you know the elements that are coming, just use display: none; then after, use jquery to bring it back

Comment: Thankfully, the css file would load much before a user's actions would cause the unwanted elements to show. 

...unfortunately, it turns out that injecting that bit of CSS will also affect future ajax-loaded modals that may want to present those elements. 

I guess one way to get around this is to use a unique ID on this problematic modal, so that your suggested CSS definitions would only target the unwanted elements on that modal. This is a candidate solution!

Comment: After reviewing, CSS really would be the best solution. It's reusable on similar future problems,of which I'm sure there will be many.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the containers where the elements will be injected before the ajax call?

```
$(containerSelector).hide();
```

Or injecting CSS. If you have other styling changes that need to be made than injecting CSS would be the way to go, otherwise just hide using jQuery.

Comment: A surprisingly simple solution. It may not work for my particular situation, but it could be a general solution for this kind of problem. Definitely a candidate solution.